# Meaning of 'swung around' in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was chatting with my client, and he said the following sentence in between:

> Oh, also ***swung around*** with the CreditCard folks, we'll need to do some validation against their production system at somepoint to...not sure what is involved for that to occur

Although, the exact meaning of it is not required to understand the sentence, but when I looked it on dictionary, I couldn't find any verb that fits this.

I can only guess that it means "he had a chat or conversation with the credit card folks".

Comment: As an American NE coast, to say "swung around" implies actually making a physical stop to talk "swung around bob's office to chat" or more likely "swung by Bob's office to chat." I have never heard personally "swung around with." I am curious what answers people come up with. "Swung around with" almost sounds like the client was boxing or sparring with the Credit Card people.

Comment: I strongly suspect it was ***hung** around with*.

Comment: To swing by is probably more common among the folks in in AusNZ. Also, the use of *with* sounds a little awkward to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would say that "swing" means to visit, by going out of your way. The closest relevant definition would be

> To go along or round in a curve or with a sweeping motion; to wheel, sweep

(From the OED: http://oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/195888)

Answer (score 0):

**revisit**, **follow up with**, or to use a baseball metaphor, **touched base with**.

> Oh, also *revisited with* the *CreditCard* folks, we'll need...
>
> Oh, also *followed up with* with the CreditCard folks, we'll need...
>
> Oh, also *touched base with* the CreditCard folks, we'll need...

Basically he talked with them again, and got more to work from.